# Retrofit and Moshi: Parsing a JSON Object with Two Arrays

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

In the process of learning how to use Retrofit with Moshi to use APIs with Android, I have run into an issue I cannot get my head around. The goal here is to get a simple array of categories returned from an API. When I make the call to, in this case, the Behance API to list all creativefields, an array is not returned. Instead is is an object with two arrays:

```
{"fields":[{"id":108,"name":"Advertising"},{"id":3,"name":"Animation"},{"id":4,"name":"Architecture"},{"id":5,"name":"Art Direction"},{"id":130,"name":"Automotive Design"},{"id":109,"name":"Branding"},{"id":133,"name":"Calligraphy"},{"id":9,"name":"Cartooning"},{"id":124,"name":"Character Design"},{"id":12,"name":"Cinematography"},{"id":15,"name":"Computer Animation"},{"id":19,"name":"Copywriting"},{"id":20,"name":"Costume Design"},{"id":21,"name":"Crafts"},{"id":137,"name":"Creative Direction"},{"id":23,"name":"Culinary Arts"},{"id":122,"name":"Digital Art"},{"id":27,"name":"Digital Photography"},{"id":28,"name":"Directing"},{"id":110,"name":"Drawing"},{"id":31,"name":"Editing"},{"id":32,"name":"Editorial Design"},{"id":33,"name":"Engineering"},{"id":35,"name":"Entrepreneurship"},{"id":36,"name":"Exhibition Design"},{"id":37,"name":"Fashion"},{"id":93,"name":"Fashion Styling"},{"id":38,"name":"Film"},{"id":112,"name":"Fine Arts"},{"id":40,"name":"Furniture Design"},{"id":41,"name":"Game Design"},{"id":43,"name":"Graffiti"},{"id":44,"name":"Graphic Design"},{"id":131,"name":"Icon Design"},{"id":48,"name":"Illustration"},{"id":49,"name":"Industrial Design"},{"id":50,"name":"Information Architecture"},{"id":51,"name":"Interaction Design"},{"id":52,"name":"Interior Design"},{"id":53,"name":"Jewelry Design"},{"id":54,"name":"Journalism"},{"id":55,"name":"Landscape Design"},{"id":59,"name":"MakeUp Arts (MUA)"},{"id":63,"name":"Motion Graphics"},{"id":64,"name":"Music"},{"id":66,"name":"Packaging"},{"id":67,"name":"Painting"},{"id":69,"name":"Pattern Design"},{"id":70,"name":"Performing Arts"},{"id":73,"name":"Photography"},{"id":74,"name":"Photojournalism"},{"id":78,"name":"Print Design"},{"id":79,"name":"Product Design"},{"id":123,"name":"Programming"},{"id":136,"name":"Retouching"},{"id":86,"name":"Sculpting"},{"id":87,"name":"Set Design"},{"id":118,"name":"Sound Design"},{"id":91,"name":"Storyboarding"},{"id":135,"name":"Street Art"},{"id":95,"name":"Textile Design"},{"id":126,"name":"Toy Design"},{"id":97,"name":"Typography"},{"id":132,"name":"UI\/UX"},{"id":120,"name":"Visual Effects"},{"id":102,"name":"Web Design"},{"id":103,"name":"Web Development"},{"id":105,"name":"Writing"}],
"popular":[{"id":44,"name":"Graphic Design"},{"id":73,"name":"Photography"},{"id":51,"name":"Interaction Design"},{"id":5,"name":"Art Direction"},{"id":48,"name":"Illustration"},{"id":49,"name":"Industrial Design"},{"id":63,"name":"Motion Graphics"},{"id":37,"name":"Fashion"},{"id":4,"name":"Architecture"},{"id":109,"name":"Branding"},{"id":102,"name":"Web Design"},{"id":132,"name":"UI\/UX"}],"http_code":200}
```

**How do I parse this JSON response to get two arrays of creative fields using Moshi and Retrofit?** Below is the setup I had anticipated would work. Now I am aware that the JSON is not a List but more of a FieldList with 2 values of "fields" and "popular", but I can't see how to extract the arrays with Moshi.

*Model of a Creative Field*

```
data class Fields(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

*Interface/Service*

```
interface BehanceService{

@GET( "v2/fields")
fun creativeField(@Query("api_key") api_key: String): Call<List<Fields>>
}
```

*The API class*

```
object BehanceAPI {
    private val BASE_URL = "http://www.behance.net/"



    val retrofittedBuilder: Retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
    }

    val behanceService: BehanceService = retrofittedBuilder.create(BehanceService::class.java)

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is how your json looks like as Java Model

```
data class Response(
val httpCode: Int? = null,
val fields: List<FieldsItem?>? = null,
val popular: List<PopularItem?>? = null)

data class FieldsItem(
val name: String? = null,
val id: Int? = null)

data class PopularItem(
val name: String? = null,
val id: Int? = null)
```

Your service will be something like this:

```
interface BehanceService{
@GET("v2/fields")
fun creativeField(@Query("api_key") api_key: String): Call<Response>
}
```

And your Api class will be something like this:

```
object BehanceAPI {
private val BASE_URL = "http://www.behance.net/"



val retrofittedBuilder: Retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
}

val behanceService: BehanceService = retrofittedBuilder.create(BehanceService::class.java)}
```

you can call it in this way.

```
BehanceAPI.behanceService.creativeField("your_key_here").enqueue(new Call<Response>(){
@Override
public void onResponse( response: Call<Response>)
{
    // Deal with the response here
    val data = response.body();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t)
{
    // Deal with the error here
}})
```

Comment: That model structure did it, thank you! Now I know how to handle this weird configuration of arrays

Comment: For anyone looking into this in future, your list classes must not be `inner`